# Prolog: find routes from one city to a collection cities

Tags: prolog

If I have a list of facts about flights, how do I write a predict to return all routes from one city to a list cities one by one? for example, all routes from `rome` to `[moscow, amsterdam]`.

```
flight(london,dublin).
flight(rome,london).
flight(rome,paris).
flight(paris,dublin).
flight(berlin,moscow).
flight(paris,amsterdam).
flight(berlin,dublin).
flight(london,newyork).
flight(dublin,newyork).
flight(dublin,cork).
flight(dublin,rome).
flight(dublin,chicago).
flight(amsterdam,hongkong).
flight(london,hongkong).
flight(dublin,amsterdam).
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Here's a hint: A route from `A` to `B` might have a direct flight from `A` to `B`, or be a direct flight from `A` to `C` and a route from `C` to `B`.

Comment: I have created a predict to return all possible routes from one city to one city, e.g trip(rome, london) returns [rome, london], [rome, paris, london] etc. But I don't know how to write a predict to return all possible routes from one city to a list of cities.

Comment: All you need is a predicate that succeeds for every route from `A` to `B`. Then use `findall`: `findall( Dest, route(A, Dest), AllDestinations ).`

Comment: findall will return all possible routes in a list. Is there a way to return each route one by one?

Comment: Sorry, your last comment showed results in a list and I misunderstood. Yes, you can do that. Include an argument to `route` which is the "running list" of intermediate destinations. Do a search on this site for `[prolog] routes` and you should be able to find lots of examples.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find all possible paths without revisiting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13170401/find-all-possible-paths-without-revisiting)

Answer (score 0):

There exist a path if there is some direct flight:

```
route(X,Y,L):-
   route(X,Y,L,[X]).

route(X,Y,L,K):-
  flight(X,Y),
  reverse([Y|K],L).
```

Or if there exist some `Z` such that `Z` is connected is `X` and `Z` is connected with `Y`.

```
route(X,Y,L,E):-
  flight(X,Z),
  \+ member(Z,E),
  route(Z,Y,L,[Z|E]).
```

If you want to find all path in one list then use `findall/3` from prolog predefined predicates.